# How do I get rid of the Eclipse Find/Replace Bar

Tags: eclipse, preferences, pydev

For searching a document, I like using the floating Find/Replace window that pops up. Lately, however, hitting <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> pulls up this Find/Replace bar at the bottom of the editor window. I suppose I wouldn't mind it so much, except instead of selecting the text to search it puts the insertion point *after* whatever I've searched for before. Very annoying. Clicking on the magnifying glass pops up the other Find/Replace dialog.

How can I get the normal dialog to pop-up by default?

I should add that for some reason search is no longer working in Preferences, so I can no longer just search for "Find" to locate the setting I might need to change. So you'll have to give me the exact location.

[image: The Find Toolbar in Question]

A little more experimenting reveals that this is PyDev-specific behavior but I still can't find the setting that needs changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a feature request to the Pydev tracker for a setting to suppress the find bar: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3097964&group_id=85796&atid=577332

Answer (score 3):

1. type Ctrl-Shift-L twice brings up Preferences window.
2. In Preferences window: type 'find bar' in the search field. This finds 'Find bar' in category 'Aptana Studio' (assuming you have Aptana Studio included in Eclipse). Click this entry 'Find Bar' to bring up the 'Find Bar' settings page.
3. On the Find Bar settings page uncheck 'Use custom find bar on Aptana editors' See shot.
   This did the trick for me!

[image: Eclipse Find Bar settings Preferences page]

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure the 'command-f' is binding with menu item 'edit' - 'find/replace...'?

Might other plug-in hook the key binding.

And another way is using 'spy' to see which one contribute it. Focus on the search widget, then click 'alt - shift - f1'.