# How can I replace the find/replace dialog?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Is there a way to replace the "in-line" find and replace box that gets attached to the bottom of the current editor with the default eclipse popup find/replace dialog?

Or is there a way to make the aptana find/replace a popup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option in preferences for Aptana. Im using version 3, and it lies in

Aptana Studio -> Find Bar -> Show Eclipse search dialog on 2nd Ctrl + F

Comment: If you'd like to get rid of the the Aptana "Find Bar" altogether you can go to the same preference pane and uncheck the "Use custom find bar on Aptana Studio editors" option.  After you do this, and relauch any open editor tabs, Apatana will use the default eclipse find/replace dialog.  Similar question here too if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814482/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-eclipse-find-replace-bar